# How to add a "sleep" or "wait" to my Lua Script?

Tags: timer, lua, sleep, wait

I'm trying to make a simple script for a game, by changing the time of day, but I want to do it in a fast motion. So this is what I'm talking about:

```
function disco ( hour, minute)
setTime ( 1, 0 )
SLEEP
setTime ( 2, 0 )
SLEEP
setTime ( 3, 0 )
end
```

and so on. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: check also [easiest-way-to-make-lua-script-wait-pause-sleep-block-for-a-few-seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034334/easiest-way-to-make-lua-script-wait-pause-sleep-block-for-a-few-seconds)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to make lua script wait/pause/sleep/block for a few seconds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034334/easiest-way-to-make-lua-script-wait-pause-sleep-block-for-a-few-seconds)

Answer (score 36):

Lua doesn't provide a standard `sleep` function, but there are several ways to implement one, see [Sleep Function](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SleepFunction) for detail.

For Linux, this may be the easiest one:

```
function sleep(n)
  os.execute("sleep " .. tonumber(n))
end
```

In Windows, you can use `ping`:

```
function sleep(n)
  if n > 0 then os.execute("ping -n " .. tonumber(n+1) .. " localhost > NUL") end
end
```

The one using `select` deserves some attention because it is the only portable way to get sub-second resolution:

```
require "socket"

function sleep(sec)
    socket.select(nil, nil, sec)
end

sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: @DonavonDecker Follow the other approaches in the link then. There are several available for windows. For example, writing a C extension

Comment: I understand, but when I try the other method in the link , I get an error saying "attempt to index global 'os' nil value"

Comment: @DonavonDecker That's odd, because `os` is a standard Lua library and I tested the one using `ping` under Windows XP myself, and it works fine. What version of Lua are you using?

Comment: I think he is using a game engine which doesn't provide the `os` library. If you are, please specify which one, as it is more likely to provide a better solution.

Comment: Is this a good solution for a game that's meant to be played on an Android mobile device?

Answer (score 8):

If you have luasocket installed:

```
local socket = require 'socket'
socket.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: How to install lua package?

Answer (score 5):

This homebrew function have precision down to a 10th of a second or less.

```
function sleep (a) 
    local sec = tonumber(os.clock() + a); 
    while (os.clock() < sec) do 
    end 
end
```

Comment: don't forget it is a busy wait, consuming processor time

Comment: If you want a no busy wait for Lua for use in frames for videogames or applications, perhaps wxLua or other libraries may provide less resource craving sleep functions.
The sleep function I provide is useful for bugtesting, automation in smaller scripts and less serious projects.

Answer (score 4):

[wxLua](http://wxlua.sourceforge.net/) has three sleep functions:

```
local wx = require 'wx'
wx.wxSleep(12)   -- sleeps for 12 seconds
wx.wxMilliSleep(1200)   -- sleeps for 1200 milliseconds
wx.wxMicroSleep(1200)   -- sleeps for 1200 microseconds (if the system supports such resolution)
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a super old question, but I stumbled upon it while I was working on something. Here's some code that's working for me...

```
time=os.time()
wait=5
newtime=time+wait
while (time<newtime)
do
  time=os.time()
end
```

And I needed randomization so I added

```
math.randomseed(os.time())
math.random(); math.random(); math.random()
randwait = math.random(1,30)
time=os.time()
newtime=time+randwait
while (time<newtime)
do
  time=os.time()
end
```

Comment: That's a ‘busy wait’.

Answer (score 1):

I needed something simple for a polling script, so I tried the `os.execute` option from [Yu Hao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17987723/13388867). But at least on my machine, I could no longer terminate the script with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. So I tried a very similar function using `io.popen` instead, and this one does allow early termination.

```lua
function wait (s)
    local timer = io.popen("sleep " .. s)
    timer:close()
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read this:
http://lua-users.org/wiki/SleepFunction

There are several solutions and each one has a description, which is important to know.

This is, what I used:

```
function util.Sleep(s)
    if type(s) ~= "number" then
        error("Unable to wait if parameter 'seconds' isn't a number: " .. type(s))
    end
    -- http://lua-users.org/wiki/SleepFunction
    local ntime = os.clock() + s/10
    repeat until os.clock() > ntime
end
```

Comment: That's a ‘busy wait’.

Comment: As I mentioned below, either `unistd` or `posix.time` provide direct access to POSIX' sleep function, on Unix systems. Idk about Windows.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a MacBook or UNIX based system, use this:

```
function wait(time)
if tonumber(time) ~= nil then
os.execute("Sleep "..tonumber(time))
else
os.execute("Sleep "..tonumber("0.1"))
end
wait()
```

Comment: Files, and thus commands, are case-sensitive on most Unix systems, except for filesystems in MacOS by default. I.e. you need `sleep` instead of `Sleep`, for most OSes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "os.time" or "os.clock" with "while" loop, i prefer "repeat until" loop because its shorter, but they are expensive because they cost full usage of a single core.

If you need something less demanding, you can use various wrappers like wxLua that i use, but sometimes, some of them also got usage penalty, specially annoying in games, so its best to test them and get what is best for your project.

Or you can relay on OS like Windows to do sleep function, using applications that exist in system32, via Batch or PowerShell, using ">nul" to hide it with "os.execute" or "io.popen", like "ping" (localhost/127.0.0.1) with timeout, "choice" (works with XP, newer versions may be different, i prefer it), "timeout" (/nobreak may be useless because all Windows commands can be canceled with CTRL+C). Downside are limited to given OS and number limitation as well as seconds or miliseconds, running it on eg. Linux may need Wine emulation for Windows (if application are written for it). You can also use "sleep" or "start-sleep" (from PowerShell), but since Lua are standalone, most people prefer pure Lua or wrappers, and you can use what suits your project.

Answer (score 0):

The safe function sleep (n) for Lua:

```
function sleep (n)
    while n > 0 do
        print("Sleeping for ".. tonumber(n) .." seconds...")
        os.execute("ping -n 2 localhost > nul")
        n = n-1
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Luaposix' `unixstd` module provides direct access to the `sleep` function on POSIX systems, i.e. Linux, MacOS and such.

```lua
local unistd = require('posix.unistd')
unistd.sleep(5)
```

`sleep` only has a second resolution, but `posix.time.nanosleep` apparently has nanosecond precision:

```lua
local time = require('posix.time')
time.nanosleep({tv_sec=5, tv_nsec=500})
```

Answer (score -3):

```
function wait(time)
    local duration = os.time() + time
    while os.time() < duration do end
end
```

This is probably one of the easiest ways to add a wait/sleep function to your script