# What am I doing wrong with this Lua code?

Tags: lua, sleep

this is my code

```
function masspoke(serverConnectionHandlerID, clientID, txt)
    local error = ts3.requestClientPoke(serverConnectionHandlerID, clientID, txt)
    sleep(1)
    local error = ts3.requestClientPoke(serverConnectionHandlerID, clientID, txt)
    if error == ts3errors.ERROR_not_connected then
        ts3.printMessage(serverConnectionHandlerID, "Error: Not Connected")
        return
    elseif error ~= ts3errors.ERROR_ok then
        print("Getting Error: " .. error .. "by poking the ID: " .. clientID)
        return
    end
    ts3.requestClientPoke(serverConnectionHandlerID, clientID, txt)
end
```

and my error is

```
attempt to call global 'sleep' (a nil value)
```

Comment: The error message is clear: you're calling an undefined global function named `sleep`.

Comment: ok so how do i add add a pause where the i want it to sleep

Comment: You find a sleep function in some library that exposes one or bind one from C yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `sleep` function in Lua, hence the error you are getting. The simplest way to achieve what you want is to use [socket.sleep](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/socket.html#sleep) if you have access to luasocket. There are several other options listed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034334/easiest-way-to-make-lua-script-wait-pause-sleep-block-for-a-few-seconds) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987618/how-to-add-a-sleep-or-wait-to-my-lua-script) SO questions.

Comment: I have tried the socket sleep and i still get the same error
>attempt to index global 'socket' (a nil value)

Comment: @JoseSeverino, you need to use `local socket = require "socket"` before calling `socket.sleep`.

Answer (score 0):

Lua does not provide a sleep function. There are several ways to implement one [as discussed on the Lua wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SleepFunction), definitely take a look. The socket based solution is a better option than a timer loop because it doesnt spin the CPU (keep it busy), but it requires that you install the third party `sockets` library. In all solutions, your app can't do anything else, it is stuck waiting for the time to elapse.

You should ask if you really need to block your thread for a set time, ie why not instead loop until a certain condition is met. In your case this could be loop until either the OK status is obtained from the request, or a certain amount of time has elapsed. This way, the loop will end as soon as your "go ahead" condition is reached, but function will return if it takes too long to reach the condition. The other advantage of this is that you might be able to give the TS app a chance to process other events, each time through the loop.

It would look like this (not tested):

```
function masspoke(serverConnectionHandlerID, clientID, txt)
    local start = os.clock()  -- start timing
    local MAX_WAIT_SECS = 1   -- seconds to wait for OK
    local error = ts3.requestClientPoke(serverConnectionHandlerID, clientID, txt)
    while error ~= ts3errors.ERROR_ok do
        if os.clock() - start > MAX_WAIT_SECS then  -- too long, give up!
            if error == ts3errors.ERROR_not_connected then
                ts3.printMessage(serverConnectionHandlerID, "Error: Not Connected")
            else
                print("Getting Error: " .. error .. "by poking the ID: " .. clientID)
            end
            return
        end
        error = ts3.requestClientPoke(serverConnectionHandlerID, clientID, txt)
    end
    -- now that ts poke is ok, do whatever: 
    ts3.requestClientPoke(serverConnectionHandlerID, clientID, txt)
end
```

I think the above is a cleaner approach, the intent is clearer. If you really want to sleep the main thread via the socket module, then put this before your `masspoke()` function:

```
require "socket"  -- you need to install socket lib manually
function sleep(sec)
    socket.select(nil, nil, sec)
end
```

But there are several other options on http://lua-users.org/wiki/SleepFunction that should be worth trying (depending on your platform, and whether you want your prog to run on multiple platforms or not) that do not require the installation of a third-party library. Make sure to read that page carefully and try out what it shows.

Comment: what is the loop syntax and where does it get placed

Comment: or where and how do I implement the socket based solution