# Applying delay between iterations of LUA for loop

Tags: for-loop, lua, iteration

I've been scratching my head at this for several hours. So i have a script that i'm calling a function 625 times but that causes lag so i want to delay each iteration of the for loop by 5 seconds. Any help would be great.

Comment: Have you looked at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987618/how-to-add-a-sleep-or-wait-to-my-lua-script

Answer (score 2):

I use this little function for second-resolution delays.

```
function os.sleep(sec)
  local now = os.time() + sec
  repeat until os.time() >= now
end
```

EDIT: Added msec version (approximate -- not very precise)

```
function os.sleep(msec)
  local now = os.clock() + msec/1000
  repeat until os.clock() >= now
end
```

Comment: Millisecond Resolution can be achieved by using `os.clock()` instead of `os.time()`.

Comment: Updated answer to include this version also.  Thanks.  However, it should be noted that according to the Lua reference, the value returned is only an approximation.