# Lua save string to file

Tags: file, file-io, lua, save

I've started using Lua for school, and I'm wondering if it is possible to save a string to a txt file?

i.e

I have a string called `shroom` and it equals `mush`.

I have a file in the same folder as the .lua file called `output.txt`.

I now want to save the string `shroom` to `output.txt`.

I then want to make a while loop and every 1 second save the string `shroom` to the `output.txt` file, overwriting the contents of `output.txt` each time i save the string.

Is this possible in Lua? I've never used Lua before and I'm really confused at the moment..

Thanks :)

Comment: The first lesson about Lua should be: [Lua is not an acronym](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615975/what-does-lua-acronym-stand-for) :-)

Comment: @Adam yeah... See I thought it was `Lua` but my prof is some old dude who spells it as `LUA` so i just went with the old man's flow...

Comment: @Brandon Well now you can school your prof. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read [this chapter](http://www.lua.org/pil/21.2.html) from Programming in Lua to see how you can work with files; you'll need to use `"w"` mode when you open file and then call `f:write(shroom)` to do the write.

For sleeping in a loop you may want to check suggestions in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034334/easiest-way-to-make-lua-script-wait-pause-sleep-block-for-a-few-seconds).